# Meteor display all users except currently logged in user

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, spacebars

i'm currently doing a simple app with Meteor which requires displaying all users except for the current logged in user.

Here's my 'users' template which displays all the users:

```
<template name="friends">
    {{#each listUser}}
        <p id="userNameOnList">{{profile.firstname}} {{profile.lastname}} <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btnAddFriend">Add Friend</a></p>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

And here's my Template Helper:

```
Template.friends.helpers({
    listUser: function(){
        return Meteor.users.find({},{sort:{'profile.firstname': 1}});
    }
});
```

I'm a bit lost from here, can you give ideas on how I could handle the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your current userId in query. I didn't test the query but it will works

```
Template.friends.helpers({
    listUser: function(){
        return Meteor.users.find({_id:{$ne:Meteor.userId()}},{sort:{'profile.firstname': 1}});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The **[docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users)** are your friend here. As it explicitly states

> Like all Mongo.Collections, you can access all documents on the
>   server, but only those specifically published by the server are
>   available on the client.
>
> By default, the current user's username, emails and profile are
>   published to the client. You can publish additional fields for the
>   current user with:

```
// server
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'other': 1, 'things': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});

// client
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```

> If the autopublish package is installed, information about all users
>   on the system is published to all clients. This includes username,
>   profile, and any fields in services that are meant to be public (eg
>   services.facebook.id, services.twitter.screenName). Additionally, when
>   using autopublish more information is published for the currently
>   logged in user, including access tokens. This allows making API calls
>   directly from the client for services that allow this.

---

Building from the above, you can customize your own publish function. You'd first need to get the _id of current logged in the user from the Mongo.users collection. Then use that in your query to return all
users minus the current logged in user:

```
// in server.js
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
    return Meteor.users.find(
        {"_id": { "$ne": this.userId }}, 
        {fields: {emails: 1, profile: 1}}
    );
});

// in client.js
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```

Comment: To add to that, using a subscription with `null` will automatically publish. So it's actually easier to use `Meteor.publish(null, function () { /** ... */ })` to publish additional info about the current user